# Generic property disadvantages?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

i use generic properties on my project,but i dont know,is there any disadvantage use them,please tell me a scenario,they have a disadvantage?my part of code below.

```
public class GenericResult<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public GenericResult<int> AddCategory(TCategory tCategory)
{
    GenericResult<int> result = new GenericResult<int>();

    //business logic validation,dont make sense,only example :)
    if (tCategory.Name.Lenght > 100)
    {
        result.IsSuccess = false;
        result.Message = "Category Name length is too long";
        result.Data = 0;
    }

    //handle .net runtime error//may be database is not aviable.
    try
    {
        result.Data = this.catalogRepository.AddCategory(tCategory);
        result.IsSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Data = 0;
        result.IsSuccess = false;
        result.Message = ex.Message;
    }
    return result;
}

public GenericResult<IEnumerable<TCategory>> GetCategoryHierarchy(TCategory parentCategory)
{
    GenericResult<IEnumerable<TCategory>> result = new GenericResult<IEnumerable<TCategory>>();
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<TCategory> allCategories = catalogRepository.GetAllCategories();
        result.Data = GetCategoryHierarchy(allCategories, parentCategory);
        result.IsSuccess = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.IsSuccess = false;
        result.Data = null;
        result.Message = ex.Message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: if AddCategory fails, why do you return an instance? this is usually considered bad practice. return null to make it clearly visible to the outside that something failed.

Comment: Agree with Mario, but throwing an exception could be more expressive in order to show everyone that something went wrong!!!

Comment: `null` gives you no message. What he's returning is a homebrew version of a `MayBe<T>` which is a good pattern in other languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to throw an exception but prefer to return a result containing either the error or the value i.e. a `MayBe` that's fine in some situations. But to be honest in this situation I'd prefer simply throwing/passing through the exception.

I'd prefer returning an immutable struct as `MayBe` instead of a mutable class like you did. It's very similar to `Nullable<T>`, except it works on reference types and can store an error. Something like:

```
public struct MayBe<T>
{
    private T value;
    private Exception error;

    public bool HasValue{get{return error==null;}}
    public T Value
    {
      if(error!=null)
        throw error;
      else
        return value;
    }

    public static MayBe<T> CreateError(Exception exception)
    {
      return new MayBe<T>(default(T),exception);
    }

    public static MayBe<T> CreateValue(T value)
    {
      return new MayBe<T>(value,null);
    }

    public static implicit operator MayBe<T>(T value)
    {
        return CreateValue(value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if(HasValue)
            return "Value: "+Value.ToString();
        else
            return "Error: "+Error.GetType().Name+" "+Error.Message;
    }
}
```

Your code becomes

```
public MayBe<int> AddCategory(TCategory tCategory)
{
    try
    {
       return this.catalogRepository.AddCategory(tCategory);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return MayBe<int>.CreateError(ex);
    }

    return result;
}

public MayBe<IEnumerable<TCategory>> GetCategoryHierarchy(TCategory parentCategory)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<TCategory> allCategories = catalogRepository.GetAllCategories();
        return allCategories;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return MayBe<int>.CreateError(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

One problem I see with this implementation is that exceptions are not completely immutable. That can cause problems if the same `MayBe<T>` throws on multiple threads. Perhaps someone can suggest a better implementation.

Comment: Because 1) It can't be `null`. Since we already handle `null` values internally having the whole `MayBe` being `null` doesn't make much sense 2) It's cheap. It has only two fields. 3) Since it's immutable there are almost no semantic differences apart from nullability.

Answer (score 4):

I'd rather removing `IsSuccess` and `Message` and returning only the object. See below...

Take a look at my question [Good practices when handling Exceptions in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917391/good-practices-when-handling-exceptions-in-c). You're returning **errors** instead of **throwing exceptions**, and in .NET, that's not suggested.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229030.aspx):

> **Do not return error codes. Exceptions are the primary means of reporting errors in frameworks.**

---

What you are doing is suggested in some articles/books I've read, including [The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer) and [this Joel Spolsky article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html), but as said by MSDN, in **.NET** exceptions are better for this purpose.

**Edit:**
If you still want to do it that way (even if that **could** bring some problems to developers that are working with your code), I think that, in general, it could be a good way. In fact, I'm going to edit the question I linked on this answer to place a link to your code for an alternative of returning *errors* instead of throwing Exceptions in .NET

Comment: but i dont want only exception handlings,i want to make easy my validation handling,i have edited my question like below

 if(tCategory.Name == null)
               {

                    result.IsSuccess = false;
                    result.Message = "Category Name cannot be null";
                    result.Data = 0;
                }

Comment: @tobias What is the difference between that and doing: `throw new ArgumentNullException("Category Name cannot be null");` or just `throw new ArgumentNullException("tCategory");`? I mean, you can still validate and let the caller know what was the error...

Comment: Not always true, imagine you are building a UI Framework or set of something that works inside a UI, if you simply throw an exception, default UI framework may fail to execute its own pending tasks. Where else this pattern is really useful when you do not want to disturb underlying framework with your exceptions and carry your tasks in little different manner.

Comment: @AkashKava That is correct. In fact, I upvoted your answer, because I agree with you in the scenario you explained (JSON, webservices,..), but my point is that it doesn't make validations easier, does it?

Comment: @Oscar, yes I feel the point about validations still depends on situation. It depends on who catches and handles validation. I guess whatever is said on MSDN is to make people aware and change their style of programming from "functional C" to "Object Oriented C#", exceptions are the best but one should choose wisely on how to incorporate them.

Comment: @Oscar
i mean,validation thourg business logic,other example,if(accountBalance<price) message="your balance is not enough";

Comment: @tobias Still don't follow you :( I mean, I can't really understand the difference (in those scenarios) between validating doing that and throwing an Exception. Of course, @Akash gave some good examples, but in your case, I just don't see the difference.

Comment: i mean,throwing an exception is from .net framework,but business logic validations dont mean .net exceptions,its simple,this way easy comminication other layer(presentation layer) and other platforms(java,mobile) but my question is generic property is the best way or not,point is this,ok?

Answer (score 2):

If your application scope is completely inside .NET scope, then this pattern is of no use and just as others have mentioned, you should let exceptions be thrown and you might want to change the exceptions.

However, if your application scope is wide that might include any other client side framework, probably via JSON, web services etc, and if client side framework does not properly support exceptions then this pattern may be useful. For example, in JSON based Javascript call, you will always expect a result, and a message indicating a failure on server side or not. Failure on client side could be either failure on server side or network failure, usually all client framework will detect and only report network failures and improperly coded framework will lead to chaos when you will not get any error report on client side of what exactly failed on server side.

One more place this pattern is very useful is, when you are writing some plugin in the UI or inside someone else's framework where just throwing exceptions can result in undesired results as after having exceptions, third party framework may say "Unexpected error" as they do not and they are not made to understand your exceptions. This pattern is useful while being inside someone else's framework and still letting underlying framework work correctly regardless of your failure. And you probably can communicate correctly within your app framework.

I recently have seen, and its still a bug, WPF stops processing some pending UI related activities if you set a source of an image that is a web address and that does not exist. You will see a network related exception traced, but WPF will incompletely stop processing anything that was in pending tasks and app still works but it does affect other UI elements where it should not.

Comment: A similar pattern is very useful in functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the automatic property is quite fine and I do not see any issues.

But I strongly discourge the pattern using a class as a result to tell the outside world that something failed. Return null or throw an exception when something badly fails.

hth

Mario

Comment: Returning `null` erases the error information, and throwing exceptions can be slow or annoying in some situations. Especially in functional programming.