# Is there a built in type in C# that contains a bool and a string for static method return?

Tags: c#, .net, types, static-classes

I'm looking for a type to return from a function or method, to convey first, whether it was successful or not, and then attache a message (as a string) to it to pass further information about why it failed. It might be something on the lines of an Application Exit Code; however, I don't to create a whole set of exit codes to index a particular error message. I do like the idea of a single "success" exit code so one can quickly check whether the call failed or not and work accordingly.

I wanted to make this the return type of a series of static methods (like service calls), and for which I could just create a class with those two fields (bool and string); however, I feel something like these might exist already, although I haven't been able to find it. Also, if there are better practices to handling the return from a method to obtain this sort of info, or a general rule against these sort of static classes altogether, I welcome your comments.

For better visualization:

```
    public static <type> CreateSomething(string somethingName)
    {
        ...
        return new <type>("Fail!", "Because...");
    }
```

Comment: Related question (but probably not an exact duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919700/generic-property-disadvantages

Comment: Not looking for a Generic type, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two obvious approaches to this: define your own type or use `Tuple<T1, T2>`.

I would argue that you should almost always just define your own type. It costs nothing. Just do it. That’s how you’re meant to do it.

If you’re feeling particularly lazy though...

```
public Tuple<bool, string> MyMethod(...)
{
    ...
    return Tuple.Create(false, "Something broke");
}
```

Comment: A tuple doesn't solve this. You rather need a discriminated union. You have either an error or a value.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I would agree with the sentiment that a tuple is a _bad_ approach to representing this information. However, the OP asks for a type with a bool and a string, so the OP gets a type with a bool and a string.

Comment: Besides, there were are already enough answers suggesting alternatives with no answers suggesting how to do the exact thing asked.

Comment: This "tuple" is a strangely good idea, but you're right: it's the same thing as a custom class. I was just wondering whether there was a built-in just for returns, or a best practice in the subject. In either case, you answered both.

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is called [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Here is the [Microsoft intro to generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and there is plenty online about them, also.

More to your question, also, you can combine generics with the [TryCan pattern](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/the-trycan-pattern/). However, often times you will want to just bubble an exception, so think this through properly

Comment: I'm not looking for a generic type, though: I want to return both types in every case. I'll look more into the TryCan pattern, however.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new type you can follow the TryDoSomething pattern in the .NET framework.

For example:

```
int number;
if(Int32.TryParse(value, out number))
{
   Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

You can create a method that returns a boolean to signal success or failure. It can also return out parameters for an error message.

Answer (score 1):

It's an Exception.

Your function should not return a true/false for success.  It should be a void that throws an exception if it fails.

...And don't forget to put the exception in the XML comments of the method.

Comment: That's far too general a statement. A `MayBe` pattern is often nicer that exceptions.

Comment: Yes, sometimes you only want exceptions to be the really serious stuff, and things that you can take care or ignore not to be exceptions, or at least have them taken care of at some lower level.  I don't like having Try/Catch statements all over the place to handle ignore-able errors.

Comment: And then what? The idea is to handle exceptions and work around then, not just let the program fail. That's just bad practice.

Comment: @rae1n: You are supposed to handle exceptions.  The method should either complete successfully, "as advertised," or it should throw a typed exception.  Throwing the exception is not a bad practice.  Not catching them, *By Type* when they happen is.  If you don't care why a method failed, then use the bool TryStuff(source, out ref dest){} pattern.  If you create a method, it either works as advertised or throws an exception.  Anything else is bad design.

Comment: Letting an application fail for manageable reasons is what I consider bad practice. Like I said, the idea is handle the exceptions; if you want to throw them, sure, but to catch them somewhere else. Having the application crashing constantly because you want to make a point of "It's not suppose to work this way" is what I consider bad practice.

Comment: @rae1n:  I can't tell if you're just not getting it, or if you're trolling, but *YOU* are supposed to handle exceptions in your code.  Apps don't fail because exceptions are thrown.  Apps fail because exceptions are not caught.

Comment: You don't get it: I'm agreeing with you. _I'M_ handling exceptions. Your original response said "It should be a void that throws an exception if it fails", and I don't agree with _that_, since throwing exceptions is not exactly handling them. See your original answer and maybe you'll understand why I disagree with it.

Comment: Maybe we're just on different wavelengths.  The function is supposed to throw the exception.  The caller to the function is supposed to catch the exception.  A custom exception class that inherits from System.Exception will do everything you want done.  If I'm just not on your frequency, then my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The core assemblies of .net don't contain such a type. You can find `Option<T>` in the F# runtime.

I also posted such a type in an older question on SO: [Generic property disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919700/generic-property-disadvantages/5919797#5919797)

Comment: I'm not looking for a generic type, though: I want to return both types in every case.