# a question about exception in c#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, invalidoperationexception

following is a code snippet:

```
class xxx
{

  public xxx(){}

  try
  {
    throw new Exception(InvalidoperationException);
  }
  catch(Exception x)
  {
  }
  catch(InvalidoperationException x)
  {
  }
}
```

can anyone tell which exception will raise here and what is the reason behind it.

Comment: "following is a code snippet" - not one that compiles.

Answer (score 8):

Wow, lots of problems here. Where to start?

1. That code won't compile. The `try-catch` block that you've defined is outside of any method, which is not allowed. You need to move it *inside* of a method.
2. Never throw a method that you intend to catch yourself later in the method. That's commonly known as using exceptions for "flow control", which is roundly discouraged. There is a performance cost associated with doing so, and it also makes it very confusing to monitor the exceptions that are being thrown when using a debugger when you have code that's throwing and catching it's own exceptions. Use boolean variables (known as flags) for flow control, if necessary.
3. Always catch the *most* derived exception class first. That means you should catch `InvalidOperationException` first, *before* trying to catch `Exception`. You need to reverse the order of your `catch` blocks in the code that you have.
4. You should practically **never** catch `System.Exception`. The only exceptions that you should catch are those that you *explicitly* understand and are going to be able to handle. There's virtually no way that you're going to know what went wrong or how to handle it when the only information you have is that a generic exception was thrown.

   Along those same lines, you also should **never** throw this exception from your own code. Choose a more descriptive exception class that inherits from the base `System.Exception` class, or create your own by inheriting from the same.

I see that other answers are showing you sample code of what your code *should* look like, were it to be rewritten. I'm not going to do that because if I rewrote your code to be correct, I'd end up with this:

```
class Xxx
{
    public Xxx()
    {

    }
}
```

Not particularly helpful.

Comment: The performance cost (when not using a debugger) is generally over-stated; however, I agree it is still not a good idea. I disagree with the "never catch `System.Exception`; for example, "log and rethrow", or a few other scenarios it isn't unreasonable.

Comment: @Marc: There are almost always better ways to log unhandled exceptions than catching and rethrowing. For WinForms, the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` is a great place to start. I'm not much for blanket statements either, but in almost every case I see code catching `System.Exception`, it's wrong. And you certainly shouldn't catch `System.Exception` anywhere but a top-level exception handler. That's not what the above code demonstrates.

Comment: if you hit `UnhandledException`, your app is toast; and there are a number of exceptions that *don't hit this* - of course, they're pretty severe *anyway*, so probably uncatchable via any route.

Answer (score 2):

If the code is like this

```
 class xxx
    {

      public xxx(){

      try
      {
        throw new Exception(InvalidoperationException);
      }

      catch(InvalidoperationException x)
      {
      }
```

catch(Exception x)
          {
          }
        }
        }

It should compile and raise your exception and catch. Otherwise your code will not compile at all.

Comment: Which logic is this ? It would never compile.

Comment: yeah it will not compile, as the "Exception" class should be at end of any other classes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No exception will be thrown as this code will not even compile.

Regardless - several points:

- When using exception handling, put the more specific exception before the less specific ones (so the catch of `InvalidOperationException` should be before the one for `Exception`).
- Catching `Exception` is normally no very useful.
- If you catch an exception, do something with it.

---

You probably meant:

```
throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

However, the way you structured your exceptions, the `catch(Exception x)` block would have run.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
class xxx
{
    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
          throw new InvalidoperationException(); 
        }
        catch(InvalidoperationException exception)
        {
            // Do smth with exception;
        }            
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            throw; // Rethrows your exception;
        }
    } 
}
```

`InvalidOperationException` inherits from `Exception`.
`catch` tries to processes the most specific branch, so `catch (InvalidOperationException x)` will be executed here.

Comment: You should also reorder the `catch` blocks - the first block that matches will run, not the most specific (since all exceptions inherit from `Exception`).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It wouldn't compile. So, it there's no question about as to which exception will be generated.

Your code should be something like this :

```
class xxx
{
    public void Test()
    {
        try
        {
          throw new InvalidoperationException(); 
        }
        catch(InvalidoperationException exception)
        {
            // Something about InvalidOperationException;
        }            
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            // Something about the Exception
        }
    } 
}
```

Point to be noted :

1. Write more specific class of Exception first, hence we write InvalidOperationException prior to Exception class.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the compile issue.... the first matching exception block (`catch(Exception x)`) will get the exception. You then *ignore* the exception and don't re-throw, so exception will be seen by the outside world. That doesn't make it good practice, though... in particular, catching an arbitrary `Exception` and ignoring it is risky - it could have been *anything*... it isn't necessarily the exception you thought it was.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code won't compile, but I'll just ignore that...

If I'll just look at the line:

```
throw new Exception(InvalidoperationException);
```

1st of all, according to MSDN there is no such constructor. So I will assume you meant the constructor: Exception(String msg, Exception innerException). Meaning:
    throw new Exception("blabla", InvalidoperationException);

The exception that is being thrown is of type *Exception* and not *InvalidOperationException*. So **ONLY**  catch(Exception x) can catch it.

If you would've thrown *InvalidoperationException* than the way you wrote the order of the catches, the Exception class would get caught *first*.
The order of the catches does matter.

The best advice I can give you is simply **try it yourself** and see what happens.