# C# Re-throwing Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, exception

When throwing exceptions between multiple methods, should all methods re-throw the exception? for example

```
Method1()
{
   Method2();
}

Method2()
{
   try
   {
      // Do something
   }
   catch
   {
      throw;
   }
}
```

---

```
try
{
   Method1();
}
catch
{
   // Do something about exception that was thrown from Method2()
}
```

Notice how in `Method1()`, I didn't need to wrap `Method2()` in a `try` block, should I be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not need to try, catch, and rethrow exceptions unless you have some particular reason for catching them in the first place. Otherwise, they'll *automatically* get bubbled up from the lower level functions that throw them to the highest level function in your code. Essentially, you can think of them as getting "rethrown" all the way up, even though this isn't technically what is happening.

In fact, most of the time that you see a `try`/`catch` block written, it's incorrect. **You should not catch exceptions unless you can actually handle them.** It's utterly pointless (and in fact considered to be bad practice) to catch exceptions just to rethrow them. Do not wrap all of your code within `try` blocks.

Note that by "handle them", I mean that your code in the `catch` block will take some specific  action based on the particular exception that was thrown that attempts to *correct* the exceptional condition.
For example, for a [`FileNotFoundException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx), you might inform the user that the file could not be found and ask them to choose another one.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827628/main-method-code-entirely-inside-try-catch-is-it-bad-practice/4827646#4827646) for more detail and a thorough discussion of "exception handling best practices".

Comment: as much as I understood writing `catch(Exception ex)` is a bad practice, it's much more better to catch some specific error like `ArgumentNullException` or smth like that? And why is that? And one more thing is why everyone is putting a `throw;` at the end of catch statement? Why the exception should be throwed again? Because of some higher handler which should catch and process him ?

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to wrap everything in `try` blocks.

You should only `try` when you want to `catch` something, and you should only `catch` something in the following cases:

- You're ready to *handle* the exception (do whatever needs to be done and don't let it propagate up the stack),
- You want to do something with the exception (e.g. log it) before rethrowing it (by using the parameterless form of `throw`),
- You want to add details to the exception by wrapping it in another exception of your own (see Allon Guralnek's excellent comment below).

Comment: +1: concise and accurate. I'd add one more reason that isn't exactly 'rethrowing' - wrap an exception inside a different exception (but always keep the original exception in the InnerException, otherwise you lose information about the original exception which could aid debugging). Wrapping could give additional context that rethrowing cannot, e.g. "Failed to save a new order for Customer 843, see InnerException for details.".