# Storing the data in table ( SQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am new to this programming field basically i from electrical field. now i learn SQL concepts.i have one database in that database had two table. my database name is "**MyDataBase**",and first table name is  "Assets" then my second tale name is "**AssetAssigneeMapper**".

First table columns are (Assets)

```
    assetId int (Identity),
    assetName varChar(100),
    modelNo varChar(100),
    price decimal,
    quantity int.
```

My second table columns are (AssetAssigneeMapper)

```
    assignId int (Identity),
    assetId int(Foreign Key ),
    assignedQty int,
    employeeName varChar(100).
```

I successfully store the data in my first table (Assets) by my coding but when i try to store data in second table, Compile is jumped to "catch" part.

here is my code

This code is for store data in first table

```
try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the asset name");
                    string assetName = (Console.ReadLine()).ToLower();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the model number");
                    string modelNo = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the price of the asset");
                    decimal price = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the quantity ");
                    int quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    using (var db = new MyDataBaseEntities())
                    {
                        db.Assets.Add(new Asset()
                        {
                            assetName = assetName,
                            modelNo = modelNo,
                            price = price,
                            quantity = quantity
                        });
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        Console.WriteLine("New asset '{0}' Added in database successfully", assetName);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the proper input");
                    AddSingleAsset();
                }
```

My code for store the data in second table is

```
try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the asset name to assign");
                    string assetName = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

                    using (var database = new MyDataBaseEntities())
                    {
                        var Check = database.Assets.FirstOrDefault
                                         (x => x.assetName == assetName);
                        if (Check.assetName == assetName)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("How many asset to be assigned to employee");
                            string qty = Console.ReadLine();
                            int quantity;
                            if (int.TryParse(qty, out quantity))
                            {
                                if (Check.quantity >= quantity)
                                {

                                    Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the employee");
                                    String employeeName = Console.ReadLine();

                                       database.AssetAssigneeMappers.Add(new AssetAssigneeMapper()
                                        {
                                            assignedQty = quantity,
                                            employeeName = employeeName
                                        });
                                        database.SaveChanges();

                                    Check.quantity = Check.quantity - quantity;
                                    database.SaveChanges();
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0}[{1}]-Quantity has successfully assigned to {2}", assetName, Check.modelNo, employeeName);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Quantity level is lower than your requirment");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Given Quantity input is INVALID");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Given Asset name is not available in database");
                        }


                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                }
```

When i compile above(**AssetAssigneeMapper**) code, my result is below

[SAMPLE OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtjQl.jpg)

Any one please point out what i did wrong also suggest me right way

Comment: Don't wrap your code [inside try/catch without reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4827646/529282). Had you let the exception went through, VS can tell you where the error happen & its type.

Comment: Your second table has id attribute for the asset, not name. Instead pass id of the asset and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 1):

i got my desired output,
what i did in here is ,i defined "assetId" is a "not null" type.In above code i didn`t add text to store **assetId** so only i get wrong output.

right code is below

```
database.AssetAssigneeMappers.Add(new AssetAssigneeMapper()
                                    {
                                        assignedQty = quantity,
                                        employeeName = employeeName,
                                        assetId=Check.assetId
                                    });
                                    database.SaveChanges();
```